# EXCEL VBA: Userform Code, Repetitive Code Improvement

Tags: excel, class, vba, combobox, userform

Is there a more efficient way for me to write this userform code?

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()

'do stuff

    With Item1_DropDown
        .AddItem "Monday"
        .AddItem "Tuesday"
        .AddItem "Wednesday"
    End With

    With Item2_DropDown
        .AddItem "Monday"
        .AddItem "Tuesday"
        .AddItem "Wednesday"
    End With

    With Item3_DropDown
        .AddItem "Monday"
        .AddItem "Tuesday"
        .AddItem "Wednesday"
    End With

'and so on, and so on. (I have about fifty of these 'With/End With' blocks)

End Sub
```

Basically, I would like to be able to stop writing so many of these 'With/End With' blocks. Right now, I have this type of code in four of my similarly-constructed userforms. It takes up so much textspace, and it seems like a waste. Is there a better way to do this?

Please know that I've never written a class module. So, if the solution requires it I will need to be babied into it.

Thanks,

Elias

Comment: Break out the "addItem" code into a separate sub which takes a drop-down as a parameter. You can then call that like `PopulateList Item1_DropDown`.  You could also further simplify by looping through all of the controls on the form, checking the type of each, and then if it's a drop-down pass it to your sub for filling.  If you have multiple types of drop-down on the same form, you can consider using some kind of naming rule which you can use to determine how each one gets processed.

Comment: Ah, yes; I see what you mean. I have implemented something like that. Basically, I created a For loop which scrolls through each similarly named ComboBox and adds all of the items to it. The only non-sleek thing about it is that I have a line of code for each item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compartmentalize your code with subroutines :)

Assuming your dropdowns are `ComboBox` form controls:

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()

    PopulateDropDown Item1_DropDown
    PopulateDropDown Item2_DropDown
    PopulateDropDown Item3_DropDown

End Sub

Sub PopulateDropDown(cb as MSForms.ComboBox)

    With cb
        .AddItem "Monday"
        .AddItem "Tuesday"
        .AddItem "Wednesday"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. That was very clear and easy to implement. I actually should have thought about that ahead of time. Thanks.

Comment: Question #1: Why won't that code work when I put the argument in parentheses. When I write "PopulateDropDown(Item1_DropDown)" it errors out ('object required'. But when I remove those enclosing parentheses it works?

Comment: Question #2: What other ways are there to do such a thing like this?

Comment: #1, because the default value of the combobox is it's ... value. The parentheses tell the compiler to evaluate what's inside them, so you effect calling the PopulateDropDown function with "Monday" or "Tuesday", etc, which is clearly not the ComboBox object it's expecting. For a great discussion see this [Daily Dose post](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/05/01/quick-vba-tip-parentheses/).

Comment: #1 run it with out the parentheses.

Comment: #2 you might be able to do this in a loop but I haven't tried that also out might require additional logic.  You can also set a combobox.list using `split(var, ",")` where `var` is a comma delimited string.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can populate the items using `List`:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ComboBox1.List = Array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday")
End Sub
```

You could define this array (Variant) once:

```
Private days As Variant

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    days = Array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday")
    Me.ComboBox1.List = days

End Sub
```

I would also make use of the `Tag` property (of each combobox) to distinguish those that need to be populated with these values:

```
Private days As Variant

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ctl As Control

    days = Array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday")

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is ComboBox And ctl.Tag = "days" Then
            ctl.List = days
        End If
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes. I should have been using "List" instead of "AddItem". I really prefer being able to load an array into the Combobox instead of having to do it one-by-one. As my final solution, I have used a For loop which loads the same array into all of my ComboBoxes. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are quite welcome. The Tag property is useful as well, as you can just set it for those comboboxes that need to be populated, and not worry about their names.

Comment: Ah. Now I know what that "Tag" property does. Thanks. I might have to use that.

Comment: Similar Question #1: I have about 45 labels which can have their "Captions" changed upon a user's DoubleClick. Unfortunately, I have a bunch of amateur, repetitive code to capture the double clicks on each & every label. So, therefore, I have 45 private subroutines for my 45 labels. Is there a more efficient way to do this? I'll try to do some research on it while this page refreshes.

Comment: It is possible to have one event handler for multiple controls but it requires creating a separate Class. [sample](http://yoursumbuddy.com/userform-event-handler-class-multiple-controls/). I would question why you have so many controls on a single form (50 comboboxes, presumably textboxes, etc.).. but it's up to you ;)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've started to use class modules. That link you provided helped me get started (although, much research, testing, and doubt ensued). I've used a class module (incorporated with Collections & control Tags) to significantly reduce my userform code.

Comment: By the way, my userforms have the multipage control. That's why I have so many comboboxes, labels, texboxes, and buttons. I thought about using a MultiTab control instead, but I figured since some of my pages were different it wouldn't be a good idea. I've never used a MultiTab; maybe I was wrong (?).

Comment: Do you mean a `TabStrip`? With the `MultiPage` control you have to populate each page with a different set of controls. With a TabStrip you can use a single set of controls and use the `Change` event (as I recall) of the TabStrip to just change the values that are displayed in these controls. So a TabStrip is much better if each of your *pages* contain, essentially, the same set, and arrangement, of controls.

Comment: Having so many controls on a single form can make the form take an age to load, assuming you need to populate the control's values, and is daunting for a user. Generally it is an indication that the structure of your data (or database) needs to be reviewed, or you need to simplify by having buttons to produce other subordinate (perhaps modal) forms. Another option is to not populate pages other than the first until the user first visits the page (by clicking its tab), and to only show some controls when they are needed.

Comment: Oh. Well, I'm doomed for now. I was just accustomed to the Multipage, and I didn't like the immediate controls on the TabStrip. So I opted for the MultiPage. Luckily, my userforms still load in the blink of an eye. I was worried about performance, but it hasn't been an issue yet. I'll see how that goes on other machines. Thanks

Comment: Altogether, I have over 620 values being loaded into my 5 userforms. One of the userforms is actually drawing its values from all the other ones. So far, none of them take any noticeable amount of time to load. I've tried two laptops (2.00 Ghz & 1.30 Ghz each with 4GB RAM). When I update this workbook, though, I will try to make use of the TabStrip. What do you think of that?

Comment: If (when!) it comes to it, one option is to copy the entire form and delete some tabs from these two forms, having a button to show the other form. Another option is to remove the items for controls and only set these programmatically the first time they are needed. This will still impact performance, but the initial load of the form will be faster - which is what concerns most users. Anyway, good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

look into setting up a subroutine to populate it.  More info here...

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?607511-RESOLVED-Excel-VBA-How-to-add-the-same-items-to-multiple-combo-boxes

Comment: Observation #1: From your linked thread, the second guy's solution does not work for me. MS Excel 2013 doesn't seem to recognize the "Shapes" command. Compile Error: "Method or data member not found". Though, if I change it to "Controls" AND remove that OLE stuff it will work.

Comment: If the source uses `shapes` probably because it is working with controls on a worksheet nit form controls on a userfirm